# ¿Porque el boostrap 3.3.7 y el jquery 3.1.1 no son compatibles?

Tags: jquery, bootstrap-3

Lo que quiero hacer es poner un nav bar en mi app,  pero cuando pongo el jquery en v 3.1.1 y el boostrap en v 3.3.7 no me despliega el nav bar.  Agregue el boostrap. Css,  el boostrap. Js y el jquery desde su cdn.  Puse primero el jquery y despues el css de boostrap y al final el css de boostrap.  Quisiera saber si hay conflictos entre esas versiones

Ejemplo:

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.js" integrity="sha256-2Kok7MbOyxpgUVvAk/HJ2jigOSYS2auK4Pfzbm7uH60=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>





        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">


    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

Codigo del nav bar

```
              <div class="navbar">
  <a href="#home">Home</a>
  <a href="#news">News</a>
  <div class="dropdown">
    <button class="dropbtn">Dropdown 
      <i class="fa fa-caret-down"></i>
    </button>
    <div class="dropdown-content">
      <a href="#">Link 1</a>
      <a href="#">Link 2</a>
      <a href="#">Link 3</a>
    </div>
  </div> 
</div>
```

Con el boostrap 4.0.0 si funciona correctamente el bar, pero no puedo cambiar la versión porque sino el resto de la app deja de funcionar correctamente.

Comment: ¿y cuál es el código del navbar?

Comment: @shaz ya actualice el post y puse el código del nav bar

Answer (score 6, accepted):

El problema es que el `Hash` de `bootstrap.min.css` no tiene la longitud correcta y no coincide con el contenido *hasheado*:

Mensaje de la consola:

> El hash contenido en el atributo integrity tiene la longitud errónea.
>   _display.
>
> Ninguno de los hashes "sha384" en el atributo integrity coinciden con
>   el contenido del subrecurso.

Tu `Hash`

> sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1**dm**JRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u

El `Hash` correcto ([fuente](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/3.3/getting-started/)):

> sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1**dGm**JRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u

**Edito**: Después de ver tu nav, creo que también tienes algún problema con él. Debería seguir esta estructura:

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-default">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">WebSiteName</a>
    </div>
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
      <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">News</a></li>
      <li class="dropdown">
      <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Dropdown <span class="caret"></span></a>
      <ul class="dropdown-menu">
        <li><a href="#">Link 1</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Link 2</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Link 3</a></li>                 
        </ul>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</nav>
```

Con ese cambio funciona:

```html
<script
     src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.js"
     integrity="sha256-2Kok7MbOyxpgUVvAk/HJ2jigOSYS2auK4Pfzbm7uH60="
     crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<nav class="navbar navbar-default">
  <div class="container-fluid">
<div class="navbar-header">
  <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">WebSiteName</a>
</div>
<ul class="nav navbar-nav">
  <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">News</a></li>
  <li class="dropdown">
  <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Dropdown <span class="caret"></span></a>
  <ul class="dropdown-menu">
    <li><a href="#">Link 1</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Link 2</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Link 3</a></li>                 
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
  </div>
</nav>
```